# What is the main mechanism that heats air in the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science, air

During a sunny day, air is obviously hotter than at night. What is the main mechanism for this heating? I can think of three ways:

- Conduction: the air gets heated by the ground, which is warm.
- Convection: hot air convects upward.
- Radiation: air absorbs sunlight. But isn't air transparent? Is it not 100% transparent to some wavelengths?

Which of these is the most important?

Comment: I rewrote your question to hopefully make it clearer. Feel free to undo any changes you disagree with.

Comment: start maybe here ?  https://www.ucar.edu/learn/1_1_1.htm

Comment: The atmosphere is mostly transparent to the direct sunlight. However, the ground and ocean are not, so solar light is absorbed by Earth's surface which is therefore warmed. Then the question becomes, how does the warm ground and ocean transfer energy to the (low) atmosphere? Here I expect all three processes to be relevant. Air in contact with the ground is heated by conduction. Then air convection (rising air) becomes a factor. Finally, the ground radiates IR "light" at wavelengths where the lower atmosphere is _not_ transparent, so this "heat radiation" can be absorbed by the atmosphere.

Comment: Atmospheric water plays a role in some of these processes. Water vapor and clouds (droplets suspended in the air) influence the opacity of the atmosphere to various wavelengths. Also, evaporation of liquid water on the surface of the Earth transfers energy into the atmosphere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is pretty much all based on [Atmospheric Heating](https://www.ucar.edu/learn/1_1_1.htm) and I assume you mean the atmosphere that surrounds you, rather than at any great height. I am concentrating on ground heat levels up to 500 m.

In order of importance, the electromagnetic  radiation from the sun, which obviously provides the initial energy for the atmosphere to heat up during daylight.

Higher frequency  radiation has more  energy than lower frequency radiation. Most of the sun's radiant energy is concentrated in the visible and near-visible portions of the spectrum. UV radiation  accounts for a small percentage of the total radiation received from the sun, but it is  extremely important in that it has much higher energy.

It should be noted that, because of the proportion of sea to land on Earth, about 71% of the radiation from the sun falls on water.  The specific  heat capacity of seawater at $0^{\circ}$C is 3985 J kg$^{−1}$ $K^{−1}$, but because of currents and differences in sea levels, it may be difficult to estimate the true heat transfer by convection and consumption,  to the air mass above the sea water.

[image]

[image]

A graph of solar intensity by wavelength.

Image Credit: www. solarcellcentral.com

> In the atmosphere, convection includes large- and small-scale rising and sinking of air masses and smaller air parcels. These vertical motions effectively distribute heat and moisture throughout the atmospheric column and contribute to cloud and storm development (where rising motion occurs) and dissipation (where sinking motion occurs).
>
> Meanwhile, the slow rotation of the earth toward the east causes the air to be deflected toward the right in the northern hemisphere and toward the left in the southern hemisphere. This deflection of the wind by the earth's rotation is known as the Coriolis effect.
>
> To understand the convection cells that distribute heat over the whole earth, let's consider a simplified, smooth earth with no land/sea interactions and a slow rotation. Under these conditions, the equator is warmed by the sun more than the poles. The warm, light air at the equator rises and spreads northward and southward, and the cool dense air at the poles sinks and spreads toward the equator. As a result, two convection cells are formed.

[image]

Since air is a poor conductor, most energy transfer by conduction occurs right at the earth's surface.  During the day, solar radiation heats the ground, which heats the air next to it by conduction.

Finally, a small part of the energy of the sun is directly absorbed, especially by  by gases such as ozone and water vapor. Some energy is also reflected back to space by clouds and the earth's surface.

Comment: I feel the way the exposition gives the misleading impression that most of the heat comes directly from the sun. And while the picture says that evaporated water is the greatest individual source of heat listed in the diagram, it doesn't even get a mention in the text!

Answer (score 1):

Convection is most important i believe. In fluid media, the  tranfer of hest energy is primarily due to movement of particles with increased kinetic energy, bumping into other particles , transferring energy and so on. Convection also ensures almost uniform heating of the fluid medium. The other factors contribute negligibly here.

Comment: +1 because you are answering the question in one paragraph :)

Comment: @annav -- But the answer is incorrect. Radiative transfer is by far the most significant of the three.

Comment: @DavidHammen  Within the context of te quesion it is correct. The atmosphere is a poor absorber of radiation . The air gets heated by conduction on the surface and rises by convection to equilibrate in the atmosphere. cf green houses( closed cars), where convection is blocked how hot they get in the sun.

Comment: @annav -- The air near the surface gets heated mostly by radiation rather than by conduction, even at the surface. Sometimes this local heating results in convection. Other times, it doesn't. Whether it does or does not depends on the stability of the atmosphere.

Comment: @DavidHammen   the last figure here does not say  so http://www.srh.noaa.gov/jetstream/atmos/heat.html

Comment: @annav -- That figure doesn't show upward radiation at all. It's a lie to children. Here's a more detailed figure: http://science-edu.larc.nasa.gov/energy_budget/pdf/ERB_Litho_v2014.06.26.pdf . Note how radiation from the surface dwarfs conduction and convection by a factor of over 20.

Comment: @DavidHammen  That is the energy budget. Of course black body radiation keeps the earth from cooking , radiation  from atmosphere and ground. The question is about how the atmosphere heats.

Comment: @annav -- 90% of the electromagnetic energy radiated upward by the ground is absorbed by the atmosphere.

Comment: @DavidHammen . See the figure in the answer by countoten. And that depends on the humidity and cloud content mainly. The atmosphere gases are  mainly transparent  except for the small contributions of CO2 and  methane ( small with respect to water vapor)

Comment: In Greece, in the summer if there are no north windsatmospheric  temperatures reach 40 C +, with north winds they fall down to 25 and even 21 if the wind heat content is low. That is convection homogenizing heat content in atmosphere, picking up heated air next to the ground and taking it it elsewhere.